# How to generate a Self Signed OpenSSL certificate? FAILED! => {"msg": "Wrong or empty passphrase provided for private key"}

Tags: ansible

My yaml for certificates

```
- name: Ensure directory exists for local self-signed TLS certs.
  file:
    path: "{{ certificate_dir }}/{{ server_hostname }}"
    state: directory

- name: Generate an OpenSSL private key.
  community.crypto.openssl_privatekey:
    path: "{{ certificate_dir }}/{{ server_hostname }}/privkey.pem"
    size: 2048
    type: DSA
    backup: yes
    cipher: auto
    passphrase: ansible


- name: Generate an OpenSSL CSR.
  community.crypto.openssl_csr:
    path: "{{ certificate_dir }}/{{ server_hostname }}.csr"
    privatekey_path: "{{ certificate_dir }}/{{ server_hostname }}/privkey.pem"
    privatekey_passphrase: ansible
    common_name: "{{ server_hostname }}"

- name: Generate a Self Signed OpenSSL certificate.
  community.crypto.x509_certificate:
    path: "{{ certificate_dir }}/{{ server_hostname }}/fullchain.pem"
    privatekey_path: "{{ certificate_dir }}/{{ server_hostname }}/privkey.pem"
    csr_path: "{{ certificate_dir }}/{{ server_hostname }}.csr"
    provider: selfsigned
```

When I run ansible playbook I got error

```
TASK [Generate a Self Signed OpenSSL certificate.] *****************************
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Wrong or empty passphrase provided for private key"}
```

I looked at [x509 exmaples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/x509_certificate_module.html#examples)

```
 community.crypto.x509_certificate:
    path: /etc/ssl/crt/ansible.com.crt
    privatekey_path: /etc/ssl/private/ansible.com.pem
    csr_path: /etc/ssl/csr/ansible.com.csr
    provider: selfsigned
```

No password at all.
Why I am getting error like the above posted?

Comment: You specified on the second step that the passphrase is ansible, for the private key, the module 509 is failing to use that key because it has that "passphrase" you need to indicate it to the 509 module to be able to acces that key.
Check this link: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/x509_certificate_module.html#parameter-privatekey_passphrase

Comment: @ikora Yes,but if I add passphrase it will not resolve the situation.

Comment: @ikora sorry.works fine now.You can add the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i stated on the  comments you forgot to put the passphrase that you used on the second step:

```yaml
 community.crypto.x509_certificate:
    path: /etc/ssl/crt/ansible.com.crt
    privatekey_path: /etc/ssl/private/ansible.com.pem
    csr_path: /etc/ssl/csr/ansible.com.csr
    provider: selfsigned
    privatekey_passphrase: ansible
```

More on: [Doc about x509](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/x509_certificate_module.html#parameter-privatekey_passphrase)